# Verify if the database is empty in neo4j

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I'm working on neo4j in java and I have one question. When I create a node, how can I verify that the database is empty?

Here's my code to create a node:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while (br.ready()==true) {
            transaction = graphDb.beginTx();
            int cont = 0;//limitador de tuplas por query
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && cont < 10000) {

                String[] dado = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                // inserir comando para criar o nós com a data
                Node no = graphDb.createNode();
                no.setProperty("data", dado[0]);
                no.setProperty("temperatura", dado[1]);
                no.setProperty("latitude", dado[2]);
                no.setProperty("longitude", dado[3]);
                no.setProperty("variação", dado[4]);

                System.out.println(cont);
                cont++;
            }
            transaction.success();
            transaction.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

[Execute a cypher query from java](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html).

Use this query:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n);
```

If the answer is zero, the database is empty.  If it's anything else, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATED ANSWER*

Here is an efficient Cypher query that returns a boolean `isEmpty` result.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)
RETURN n IS NULL AS isEmpty
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This returns no result if there are no nodes, even if you expect `isEmpty` to be `true`.

Comment: @Gigabyte: Good point. I think the original answer worked in 2015. I have updated my answer to include `OPTIONAL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
match (n) 
return 1 
limit 1
```

I hope Neo4J would bother less processing this query, knowing it doesnt has to bother counting or bother filtering as suggested in previous answers